# Loop Audio In SoundManager without cache

Tags: html, html5-audio, soundmanager2

Is there a way to loop SoundManager without cache so it's forced to reload the source audio file every time? I can get it to loop, but I can't get it to not cache.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
soundManager.url = '../../swf/soundmanager2.swf';
soundManager.debugMode = true;
soundManager.consoleOnly = true;

soundManager.onload = function() {
soundManager.createSound({
id:'mySound1',
url:'path/to/audio.mp3',
stream: true
});
loopSound('mySound1');
}

function loopSound(soundID) {
window.setTimeout(function() {
soundManager.play(soundID,{onfinish:function(){loopSound(soundID);}});
},1);
}</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For now, this is a solution I came up with:

```
<script>
soundManager.setup({
  url: '../swf/',
  // optional: use 100% HTML5 mode where available
  // preferFlash: false,
  onready: function() {
   var sound = soundManager.createSound({
 id: 'mySound1',
 url: 'path/to/audio.mp3',
 onfinish: function() {
  soundManager._writeDebug(this.id+' has finished the current track, now loading next track.');
  // destroy this sound
  this.unload();
  soundManager.createSound({
 id: 'mySound1',
 url: 'path/to/audio.mp3',
});
  soundManager.play('mySound1');
 },
 autoPlay: true
 });

  }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the id: to a different one will avoid needing to clear the cache.

It seams to be that even though the path to the URL is different, if the ID is the same, the song will be replayed.

if change the:

```
id: 'mySound1',
```

so that it is unique for each unique track the new song will play.

```
id: 'mySound1'+id,
```

Answer (score 0):

```
...
onload: function(){
                  if(this.readyState==2){ //ERROR HTML5 player
                      console.log('ERRORS readyState');
                      stop_play(id); // function stop play id
                      start_play(url); // function start play
                  }
},
...
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please add some description to your answer to explain why this should work for the question